# open connected subset of semi-Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I know that an open subset of a Riemannian manifold is a Riemannian manifold. Can we say that an open connected subset of a semi- Riemannian  manifold is also a semi- Riemannian manifold?

Comment: Unless your definition of semi-Riemannian is very weird, yes. In all likelyhood, the exact same proof you have of the first fact proves the second one.

Comment: I don't know its direct proof and i concluded the Riemannian case by  using a result that "every manifold can be given Riemannian structure".It would be great if can tell me its other direct proof.Thanks!

Comment: That argument is rather absurd! Simply consider the restriction of the (semi-)Riemannian structure to the open set.

Comment: The result i stated is given in the book "geometry of differential forms by Morita in ch-4 but i forgot to write that  the manifold should be smooth.The point i am stuck on is that how would i ensure that the tangent space corresponding to the open subset of a smooth semi - Riemannian manifold would be non-degenerate  w.r.t the induced metric structure as the semi- Riemannian metric is indefinite.The definition of semi- Riemannian mmetric is "It is a non-degenerate (0,2) tensor field g on M which smoothly assigns to each point p of M, a scalar product on the tangent space ."

Comment: The tangent space at a point to the open subset is the same space as the tangent space at that point to the whole manifold.

Comment: How? Can u explain it little precisely? How should i proceed?Is there any book in which i can get it?

Comment: I have confusion about that statement also because an open subset of a manifold is a submanifold and hence would have dimension less than that of the manifold and we know that a tangent space  as a vector space has same dimension as that of the manifold so if  as u said the tangent space at a point to the open subset is the same space as the tangent space at that point to the whole  manifold then we get a contradictory statement.

Comment: Well, no. Not all submanifolds have strictly lower dimension: precidely the open submanifolds are the exception. You should consult a textbook on this subject: Lee's book on smooth manifolds is a great choice.